# Convert std::vector<const Type*> to const std::vector<T, A> &Vec

Tags: c++, std

I have inherited some code and am stuck on what I thought should be a simple update.

I have the following function

```
template<typename T>
class ArrayRef { 
public:
typedef const T *iterator;
typedef const T *const_iterator;

private:
/// The start of the array, in an external buffer.
const T *Data;

public:
/// Construct an ArrayRef from a std::vector.
template<typename A>
ArrayRef(const std::vector<T, A> &Vec)
: Data(Vec.empty() ? (T*)0 : &Vec[0]), Length(Vec.size()) {}
};
```

And I need to pass a vector, defined with following, to that function.

```
std::vector<const myType*> myVector(4);
```

What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: Are `T` and `A` template arguments to the function? In that case it should just work. If they aren't, what types are they and how does `T` relate to `myType`?

Comment: I put in the entire function definition, does this make it more clear?

Comment: What is `T` in your code?

Comment: [Could you be even more explicit?](http://ideone.com/z2b0EH).

Comment: Here is the entire header file (including the function in question)http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/ArrayRef_8h_source.html

Comment: @SamCoulter Two things: What's the definition of the object of type `ArrayRef` you're passing it to? What's the error?

Comment: @SamCoulter: You're still not showing what *instance* of the `ArrayRef` class template you are using: in other words, what is the type argument you provide for `T` when instantiating `ArrayRef<>`? Is it `ArrayRef<const myType*>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass your vector:

```
ArrayRef<const myType*> myArrayRef(myVector);
```

Is there some reason this doesn't work for you?

Comment: This is correct, there was a compilation error somewhere else that prevented this from working (and spat out an error message pointing at this line). Fixed now. Thanks for your answer.